# Selenium if locate on screen unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, error-handling

I'll keep this question simple:
I have an if statement:

```
if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "mission_countdown")]'):
```

And i get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id, "mission_countdown")]"}
```

Why do I get this? I mean its an if statement, IF its on screen

Thanks for helping

Comment: if it is on screen execute whatever you have defined, if it is not, what is the code you have used? have you defined an else clause to check if it is NOT on screen ?

Comment: If it's not on screen he just had to print hi, and no I don't have an else clause to check if it's not on screen

Comment: maybe you should add in an else clause cause if it is not on screen it crashes because there is no condition to check

Comment: I added an elif not on screen now and it still is stuck on the first if, saying me it's not locatable

Comment: If its on-screen everything works but not if its not on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath` can return

- `WebElement` (if any found)
- `NoSuchElementException` (if not found)

If you're searching for the output that can be evaluated as boolean to use in `if`/`else` block, try `find_elements`:

```
if self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "mission_countdown")]'):
    print('At least one element was found')
else:
    print('No elements found')
```

Comment: I dont really know why, because its only one element on the screen, but this works :)

Comment: @LaurenzZ unlike `find_element_by_xpath ` `find_elements_by_xpath ` returns list of WebElements or empty list `[]`. Output in both cases can be evaluated as boolean value: non-empty list is always `True`, empty list is always `False`, so you can use it in `if`/`else` - it will never lead to exception

Comment: @LaurenzZ If you don't understand this, you should read it a few more times until you do. This is really important information and will be useful to you if you plan to continue to write Selenium code.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is an example. 
It explicitly waits and moves to the object element you want to find. Adding in the try will throw the except error message if it does not find the element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#--------
# all other code to begin scraping here
#--------

try:
    if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "mission_countdown")]'):
       print("found this button")

    elif: 
        print("not found trying new button ")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath here")

except:
    print("ERROR MESSAGE: NO ELEMENT FOUND")
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to wait until its there, because it's not always there. I want it to click on a specific button if its there and on a different if its not... but thanks

Comment: ok then if you do not want to wait then simply use try: except and if elif. I have made edit

Comment: This doesn't work either, but I have the solution... I just had to write find_element **S** thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `try...catch` block.If it is not their it will go to catch block.Let me know if this work for you.

```
try:
    if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "mission_countdown")]'):
        print('found')
except:
    print('Not found')
```